# Repeated Measures ANOVA DFd is zero

Tags: r, anova

I have a data set composed of 2 subjects and measures 8 times for each subject.

```
dat <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 2, 2), rep(c("t1", "t2"), 2), c(50, 52, 49, 51))
colnames(dat) <- c("subject", "time", "result")
dat <- dat %>% mutate(subject = as.factor(subject)) %>%
mutate(time = as.factor(time))
```

and so on for the rest of the 6 times left.

I am trying to apply a repeated-measures ANOVA to see if the effect of time is significant for each subject, but I keep getting DFd is zero, when it is actually 1.

```
aov <- dat %>% anova_test(dv = result, wid = subject, within = time, type = 2, detailed = TRUE)
get_anova_table(aov, correction = "none")
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What does DFd stands for?

Comment: is the denominator degrees of freedom

Comment: I get Dfd = 1, how do you say zero?

Comment: I get it 0 as well as SSd an ofc that hits p = NaN. But I can't understand why. If I try to filter the data from a larger data set it also happens. Say I am studying 2 different samples under those conditions and want to check each one separately. If I filter the data for sample 1 it also happens that way.

Comment: I get this: https://i.imgur.com/7xVNWsm.png